# Subset genes (words) and combinations of genes (words)

Tags: r

I have a data.frame in which I have gene names (rows) that look like this:

```
  ABCB1    
  ABCB1 /// ABCB4      
  ABCB4     
  ABHD14A /// ACY1
  ABHD14A      
  BOLA2 /// BOLA2B   
  ATF6B         
  ATF6B /// TNXB      
  TNXB
```

For some rows I have the single gene name (ex: ABCB1 and ABCB4) and the combination of gene names (ex: ABCB1 /// ABCB4) while for other rows there's only the combination (ex:BOLA2 /// BOLA2B). I would like to subset the situation in which I have the single genes reported as single rows and the combination of them. Can anyone help me please?

Expected output:

```
  ABCB1    
  ABCB1 /// ABCB4      
  ABCB4     
  ABHD14A /// ACY1
  ABHD14A    
  ATF6B         
  ATF6B /// TNXB      
  TNXB
```

Best.

Comment: Why is `ABHD14A /// ACY1 ABHD14A` also present in the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
Val1 <- sub(' ///.*', '', df$Col1)
Val2 <- sub('.*/// ', '', df$Col1)

ind1 <- duplicated(Val1)|duplicated(Val1,fromLast=TRUE)
ind2 <- duplicated(Val2)|duplicated(Val2,fromLast=TRUE)
df[ind1|ind2,,drop=FALSE]
 #              Col1
 #1            ABCB1
 #2  ABCB1 /// ABCB4
 #3            ABCB4
 #4 ABHD14A /// ACY1
 #5          ABHD14A
 #7            ATF6B
 #8   ATF6B /// TNXB
 #9             TNXB
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(Col1 = c("ABCB1", "ABCB1 /// ABCB4", "ABCB4", 
 "ABHD14A /// ACY1", "ABHD14A", "BOLA2 /// BOLA2B", "ATF6B",
 "ATF6B /// TNXB", "TNXB")), .Names = "Col1", class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```